# How to best modify an array using .each

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I am using Ruby, and I am relearning arrays and trying to better understand them. I know what they are but have never fully utilized them. I have an array, odds, and wanted to double every number in it. I came up with the below solution; however, I wanted to see if there was a more elegant/simple solution to my problem.

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]

odds.each do |x|
    odds[odds.index(x)]=x*2
end
```

end result is `odds = [2,6,10,14,18]`

Comment: You didn't specify the programming language you use. Please tag the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `map!` enumerator to modify every item in an array:

```
odds.map!{ |x| x*2}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to modify in place, and you really want to use `each`, I guess your approach is as good as any. It doesn't feel idiomatic, but it does meet your stated constraints.

Here are some more common approaches:

**Array.map**

Mapping the array with `map` won't modify the original array (it's not *in-place*), which is often a good thing, but it might not be what you're looking for:

```
odds.map { |x| x*2 }
```

**Array.map!**

If you really do want to modify the original array, you can use `map!` to map *in-place*:

```
odds.map! { |x| x*2 }
```

**Array.each_index**

You did ask specifically about `each`, so if you want to use an `each` and you want to modify the original array, `each_index` might be your best bet:

```
odds.each_index { |i| odds[i] *= 2 }
```